# jQuery validate plugin: use different multilingual error message on each required input box

Tags: jquery-validate

I am using [**jQuery validate plugin**](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), suppose I have 3 input box and they are required fields.

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" class="required" />
<input type="text" name="lastname" class="required" />
<input type="text" name="email" class="required" />
```

I want to have different error message, so I configure as below:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    messages: {
        firstname: {
            required: 'Please enter firs tname'
        },
        lastname: {
            required: 'Please enter last name'
        },
        email: {
            required: 'Please enter email'
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

However, now I want to have different multilingual error message on each required input box, so I tried to configure as below, the result is not work.

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    messages: {
        firstname: {
            required: window.lang.currentLang == 'en' ? 'Please enter email' : '請輸入電子郵件地址'
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

Could someone advise the way to configure the plugin to have different multilingual error message.

Thanks

Comment: I didn't check with the chinese message, but your solutions just works. at least, in version 1.10 it does

Comment: @11mb The function `$("#myForm").validate({ ...` will be called one time, so the first time will be defined using which language for error message. Unless we can call the function every time to get the related language of error message when validating the form. A code snippet will be appreciated for working example.